# Showing all links on catalog/seo_sitemap/product/?

Tags: magento-1.9, sitemaps, pager

Magento 1.9

How do I show all links on that page, without a pager? Is there a setting for that? I dont just want to remove the pager, but show all for example 250 entries on one page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself by commenting those 2 lines out in catalog.xml:

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.top" as="pager_top" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
<block type="page/html_pager" name="seo.sitemap.pager.bottom" as="pager_bottom" template="page/html/pager.phtml"/>
```

Maybe its helpful for someone else :-).